problems syncing MacOS 15.2 with NTP service on a DSM6.2 Synology
I'm having problems syncing MacOS 15.2 Monterey with NTP service running on a DSM6.2 Synology NAS.
$sudo sntp -sS 10.XX.XX.XX    
}
sntp: Exchange failed: Timeout
sntp_exchange {
        result: 6 (Timeout)
        header: 00 (li:0 vn:0 mode:0)
       stratum: 00 (0)
          poll: 00 (1)
     precision: 00 (1.000000e+00)
         delay: 0000.0000 (0.000000000)
    dispersion: 0000.0000 (0.000000000)
           ref: 00000000 ("    ")
         t_ref: 00000000.00000000 (0.000000000)
            t1: E9F85560.D54B9CB6 (3925366112.833184999)
            t2: 00000000.00000000 (0.000000000)
            t3: 00000000.00000000 (0.000000000)
            t4: 00000000.00000000 (0.000000000)
        offset: FFFFFFFF8B03D54F.955A31A500000000 (-1962683056.416592598)
         delay: FFFFFFFF1607AA9F.2AB4634A00000000 (-3925366112.833185196)
          mean: 0000000000000000.0000000000000000 (0.000000000)
         error: 0000000000000000.0000000000000000 (0.000000000)
          addr: 10.XX.XX.XX
}
-0.000183 +/- 0.046913 10.XX.XX.XX 10.XX.XX.XX

The last lines seems to give a valid output, but I'm confused by the error messages.
I have no problems syncing on the NAS NTP on Macs running Catalina or syncing to pool.ntp.org.
Any ideas?
